# PowerShell: a peculiar case of being unable to filter a generic List

Tags: powershell, generics

I have two system langages: English and Russian. So, `Get-WinUserLanguageList` returns two items:

```
PS> Get-WinUserLanguageList

LanguageTag     : en-US
[…]

LanguageTag     : ru
[…]
```

Though, when I'm trying to filter the results of this cmdlet, I fail:

```
PS> Get-WinUserLanguageList | Where-Object { $_.LanguageTag -eq 'ru' }

LanguageTag     : en-US
[…]

LanguageTag     : ru
[…]
```

At the same time, if I add parens around the cmdlet invocation, it suddenly starts working:

```
PS> (Get-WinUserLanguageList) | Where-Object { $_.LanguageTag -eq 'ru' }

LanguageTag     : ru
[…]
```

Being curious, I've tried to analyze the return type of this cmdlet. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/get-winuserlanguagelist?view=windowsserver2019-ps) says it should return a `System.Collections.Generic.List<Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.WinUserLanguage>`.

I've tried to check it, and this seems to be true:

```
PS> (Get-WinUserLanguageList).GetType().FullName
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.WinUserLanguage, Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]
```

And this generic `List` gets passed as *a single item* to the `Where-Object` pipeline, which is why the filtering breaks:

```
PS> Get-WinUserLanguageList | Where-Object { Write-Host "Item: $($_.GetType())"; $_.LanguageTag -eq 'ru' }
Item: System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.WinUserLanguage]

LanguageTag     : en-US
[…]

LanguageTag     : ru
[…]
```

So, my next hypothesis is that `Where-Object` is unable to filter a generic `List`. Okay, let's check it:

```
PS> $myList = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
PS> $myList.Add('a'); $myList.Add('b'); $myList.Add('c')
PS> $myList.GetType().FullName
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
PS> $myList | Where-Object { $_ -gt 'a' }
b
c
```

Nope, this works. It doesn't break even if I write the function that returns the list:

```
PS> function foo() { return $myList }
PS> foo | Where-Object { $_ -gt 'a' }
b
c
```

So, my questions are:

1. Why isn't `Where-Object` works properly with `Get-WinUserLanguageList` results?
2. Why does it suddenly starts working after I add the parens?
3. Why am I unable to reproduce the same effect with my custom instance of the same generic `List` type?

Comment: `Write-Output $myList -NoEnumerate | Where-Object { $_ -gt 'a' }` <- to reproduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why isn't `Where-Object` [working] properly with `Get-WinUserLanguageList` results?

Because `Get-WinUserLanguageList` outputs an instance of `[List[string]]` *as a single object*, by telling PowerShell to *not unroll* it.

> Why does it suddenly starts working after I add the parens?

Because nesting the pipeline in a separate statement causes PowerShell to *unroll* the list - this is PowerShell's default behavior.

> Why am I unable to reproduce the same effect with my custom instance of the same generic List type?

Because you haven't told PowerShell to *not* unroll it :)

To reproduce the same behavior that `Get-WinUserLanguageList` exhibits, try with `Write-Output -NoEnumerate`:

```
$myList = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
$myList.Add('a')
$myList.Add('b')
$myList.Add('c')

Write-Output $myList -NoEnumerate | Where-Object { $_ -gt 'a' }
```

`-NoEnumerate` tells PowerShell to not unroll the list

As to *why* this particular cmdlet behaves this way, the answer is probably just that "the developer who designed and implemented it made a bad choice".